# WPF Binding: cannot resolve symbol due to unknown datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I try to bind a CheckBox in a DataGrid but in the designer I get while hovering over `DoImport`

> cannot resolve symbol 'DoImport' due to unknown datacontext

My code is

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow">
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Import" 
                   Binding="{Binding Path=DoImport, 
                             Mode=TwoWay, 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MyWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public MyWindow(ObvervableCollection<Part> parts) {
        _parts = parts;
        MyGrid.DataContext = _parts;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Part> _parts;
    public ObservableCollection<Part> Parts {
        get { return _parts; }
        set
        {
            _parts = value;                    
            OnPropertyChanged("Parts");
        }
    }
}
```

The `_parts` is a collection of items that fill the DataGrid. The `Part` class is:

```
public class Part {
    public bool DoImport { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `CompareWindow(ObvervableCollection<Part> parts)`? Shall this be the constructor for MyWindow?

Comment: Yes, I corrected that.

Comment: @Egi: Done. Nothing special in that class.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549826/how-to-resolve-resharper-wpf-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-myvariable-due-to-u/25549827#25549827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designer cannot supply a `ObvervableCollection<Part>` instance to the MyWindow constructor, because it does not know how. so your constructor should never be called in the designer. 
that is why the designer "cannot resolve symbol 'DoImport' due to unknown datacontext".
the designer in visual studio expects a parameter-less default constructor in order to work properly.

maybe you should check that out:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/sample-data-in-the-wpf-and-silverlight-designer.aspx
or better yet ... let blend create design sample data for you.