# Not working binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

In advance sorry for my english :)

**XAML markup:**

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeRows" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeRows}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"></Setter>
        </Style>                                    
     </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
             <Label Content="{Binding DisplayColumn}"></Label>
             <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                     <Style.Triggers>
                         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseRightButtonDown">
                             <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                 <BeginStoryboard>
                                     <Storyboard>
                                         <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                             <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                         </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     </Storyboard>
                                 </BeginStoryboard>
                             </EventTrigger.Actions>
                         </EventTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                     <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <ContextMenu>
                                 <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding CommandAddDataRow}"/>
                                 <MenuItem Header="Update"/>
                                 <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
                             </ContextMenu>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                     <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"></Setter>
                 </Style>
             </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 </TreeView>
```

**C# code:**

```
public class MainWindow 
{
    public ICommand CommandAddDataRow { get; set; }
    public void AddDataRow(DataRow dataRow)
    {

    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        CommandAddDataRow = new Command<DataRow>(AddDataRow);
    }
}
```

Why does the binding work everywhere except for this line:

```
 <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding CommandAddDataRow}"/>
```

Comment: CommandAddDataRow = new Command<DataRow>(AddDataRow);

What Class is Command?

Comment: public class Command<T> : ICommand

Comment: I'm not sure about that `Command<T>` class (your own?) but where do you think the argument for the dataRow parameter is coming form? Look in your Output window, there probably is some binding error there.

Comment: There's something wrong here. What is the definition of the constructor of Command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [ReSharper WPF error: "Cannot resolve symbol "MyVariable" due to unknown DataContext"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549826/resharper-wpf-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-myvariable-due-to-unknown-datacont). At the end of the answer, it shows how to use the free Snoop utility to identify any bad DataContext at runtime.